# Color a surface with significance values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted a surface using python and matplotlib but now I want to color it by its statistical significance.

So far I did:

```
import pylab as pl   
import matplotlib.pyplot    
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = pl.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

x = N.array(intralist)    
y = N.array(interlist)

Y,X = pl.meshgrid(y,x)

z = N.zeros((21,21))

for i in range(21):
    for j in range(21):
        z[i][j]=Fslist[i][j]

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,z)

ax.set_xlabel('Intracorrelation')
ax.set_ylabel('Intercorrelation')
ax.set_zlabel('F-Score')

pl.savefig('F-score.png', dpi=600, format='png')
```

However, I also test the significance of the correlations, and I want to map the F-score with the significance in the same plot. In summary I want to plot intracorrelation (X axis), intercorrelation (Y axis), F-score (Z axis) and statistical significance (color).

I have been checking in the internet, but I haven't been lucky.

Comment: You might want to try asking on matplotlib's mailing lists.

Comment: Check out the answer to a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539944/color-matplotlib-plot-surface-command-with-surface-gradient