# Normalizing Colormap Used by Facecolors in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, physics

First off, I'm trying to plot spherical harmonics in matplotlib as they are seen here in mayavi: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_spherical_harmonics.html

Here is where I'm at:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

# Create a sphere
r = 3
pi = np.pi
cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:pi:50j, 0:2*pi:50j]


x = r * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
y = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
z = r * cos(phi)

colorfunction=special.sph_harm(3,4,theta,phi).real

norm=colors.Normalize(vmin = np.min(colorfunction), vmax = np.max(colorfunction), clip = False)
print colorfunction



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
ax.plot_surface(
    x, y, z,  rstride=1, cstride=1, norm=norm, cmap=cm.jet, facecolors=cm.jet(colorfunction))
plt.show()
```

The idea is to use `colorfunction` to colour the surface of the sphere according to the spherical harmonic. However, the output of this function is an array with negative numbers. What I need to do is 'normalize' this array so it behaves nicely with matplotlib's colormap. However, unlike the answer here, [Color matplotlib plot_surface command with surface gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539944/color-matplotlib-plot-surface-command-with-surface-gradient) , where the answer simply preforms a sloppy normalize by dividing by the largest element, I have negative elements so that just won't work. I'd ideally like to use `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` but it just isn't working on facecolors.

I know that the norm is applying to the `cmap=cm.jet`, because if I remove `facecolors` argument entirely I get a new colormap that behaves according to my `norm` function.

This is the crux of my issue, I cannot get my normalized colormap to apply to my facecolors. Any ideas?

[image]
This is the figure the above code currently generates. As you can see the negative values are cut-off entirely and the information is lost because the colormaps range is much larger than the actual values (so everything just looks blue).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this is too trivial, but:

```
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=cm.jet(norm(colorfunction)))
```

This normalizes `colorfunction`. Also, it is sufficient to define the normalization function by:

```
norm = colors.Normalize()
```

This will automatically scale the input between 0..1.

The result:

[image]

It seems that `cmap` and `norm` keywords apply to the case where one uses Z data to color the surface, so they are not useful here.

Comment: I would suggest using one of the diverging color maps here