# Plotting a 4D surface plot in Python with one dimensional data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am just beginning for plotting 4d plots which I couldn't do using spreadsheets.

I have four columns of data.

First three columns are independent variables and 4th column is dependent on all three.

I am trying to plot how the fourth column value varies depending on these 3 variables. I want to plot a surface from first 3 variables and color gradient the variation of the 4th column. If I use plot_surface option, i get error as

> ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional

Is there any way I can plot like mentioned above?

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461452/python-plot-3d-surface-with-colormap-as-4th-dimension-function-of-x-y-z

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a 4d plot with matplotlib using arbitrary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995610/how-to-make-a-4d-plot-with-matplotlib-using-arbitrary-data)

Comment: @joostblack thanks a lot! I will try this!

Comment: @greenmarker Thanks a lot! This seems to address my issue exactly!

Comment: @Mr.T thanks a lot! I will try this!