# How to plot a 4D array in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, multidimensional-array

I have an array `A` with a shape of `(75,552,552)`, where values are a function of `(depth, longitude, latitude)` `(z,x,y)` respectively.

and :

`x = np.arange(-7.03125,27.28125,0.0622)`.

`y = np.arange(-44.89006,-15.7057495,0.0529)`.

`z = np.linspace(-0.511953294, -5902.05762,75)`

`A = np.random.rand(75,552,552)`

I want to create a plot like **pcolormesh** or **pcolor** but in 4D (depth, lon, lat + Value) to look like the attached one.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(python) plot 3d surface with colormap as 4th dimension, function of x,y,z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461452/python-plot-3d-surface-with-colormap-as-4th-dimension-function-of-x-y-z)

Comment: Unfortunately no ! since my z is 1D, but in the mentioned link is 2D.

Comment: In the accepted answer linked by @ILS , z also starts as 1D...

Comment: Yes, but it is different than my arrays. Since, my Z represent only depth values, and my array A is 3D while in the mentioned link is only 2D.

Comment: You can use a scatter plot, with a downsampled data set, where the marker color represents the value of the indipendent variable. Or you can use VTK or Mayavi.