# Julia PyPlot: plot 3D surface with as face colors the norm of surface gradient

Tags: matplotlib, julia, plots.jl

Does anyone know how to plot a 3D surface with Julia's Pyplot with e.g the norm of 
the surface-gradient as the face color?

Similar to this topic for Python: [Color matplotlib plot_surface command with surface gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539944/color-matplotlib-plot-surface-command-with-surface-gradient)

Answer (score 10):

I saw this and I just HAD to make it work.  It was almost supported out of the box with Plots.jl, using the PyPlot backend.  I just had to swap out for a custom matplotlib shader to apply a different z-matrix.

You'll notice that I'm accessing numpy's gradient function (imported through `PyCall`), and I'm wrapping the gradient matrix `G` so that it doesn't get sliced into columns.  All in all... much simpler than the python example!

```
    using Plots; pyplot();
    x = y = LinRange(-5.0, 5.0, 30)
    z = sin(sqrt(Float64[xi^2+yi^2 for xi = x, yi = y]))
    surface(x, y, z, alpha = 0.7)
```

[image]

```
    using PyCall
    Gx, Gy = Plots.pynb.pymember(:gradient)(z)
    surface(x, y, z, alpha = 0.8, zcolor = wrap(G))
```

[image]

Comment: I like the concise syntax you have in Plots.jl. stevengj suggested the following in PyPlot https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/418#issuecomment-215609485

Comment: How would you do this in Plots.jl using Julia v1.5?

Comment: @Tom Breloff: would be grateful if you would update the syntax to `Julia 1.6`, as it doesn't run anymore. This is a top-ranked question/answer for the topic. Many thanks!

Comment: I can make the first part run with `surface(x, y, abs.(z), alpha = 0.7)`, getting rid of the complex part.