# Julia surface plot custom colors

Tags: plot, colors, julia, surface

In the Julia programming language, I know I can plot a surface with the "Plots" package using the command:

```
plot(x,y,z, st = :surface)
```

My question is this: instead of the colors on the surface indicating the z-value, can I make the colors indicate the values of some arbitrary function f(x,y,z) of the points on the surface? (the case f(x,y,z) = z would be the default behavior).

Comment: Which plotting package is this? Have you looked at the documentation for that package?

Comment: It's the "Plots" package. I have looked at the documentation, and it looks like the "zcolor" argument does what I want, but only for scatterplots (or maybe only 2D graphs)

Comment: Good question, I suggest you open an issue at the `Plots.jl` repository (and cross-reference to this question).

Comment: I found a solution for Matlab/Octave...but still not for Julia. You can use the "isosurface" function, and supply a 3d array of values of my function "f" as an argument after all the main arguments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925356/julia-pyplot-plot-3d-surface-with-as-face-colors-the-norm-of-surface-gradient/36928417#36928417

Comment: @TomBreloff: I saw the thread you linked to. It doesn't work for me. When I type in that code verbatim, I get an error:    "ERROR: MethodError: `py_colormap` has no method matching py_colormap(::ColorTypes.RGBA{Float64}, ::Float64)"