# 3D density plot

Tags: python, density-plot

I have a set of data X,Y,Z representing the coordinates of points that lie on the surface of a sphere. A scatter plot of this dataset on a sphere looks like this generated using ax.scatter.

Scatter plots

[image]

I was wondering how I can create a 3D density plot of this that is a colour map where the region where there are more points is a different colour compared to where there are fewer points. I tried Mayavi but it is not supported by my environment.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect for a question without any detail or code? Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40452621/8881141) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543777/8881141) SO question and see, if you can adapt them to your needs.